Error in fitTMB(TMBStruc): negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values (function glmm())
I have a data set that contains observation values for the choice of menus in a canteen (vegetarian or non-vegetarian). This is a summary of the data:
> str(nova)
tibble [17,900 × 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ccrs       : Factor w/ 1427 levels "564925","565106",..: 1077 1077 1077 1077 1077 1077 1077 1077 1077 795 ...
 $ meat       : num [1:17900] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gender     : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ member     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Mitarbeitende",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ age_group  : Factor w/ 4 levels "AK1","AK2","AK3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ age_group_2: Factor w/ 4 levels "15 - 25-jaehrig",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

I want to evaluate which variables have a significant influence on the choice of menus. The variable ccrs stands for "single campus card holder" and belongs uniquely to a single person.
To begin with I want to set up a global model that includes all variables. From there I try to evaluate which variables do not have a significant impact on the model and can be thrown out. The variable ccrs will therefore be included as a randomized variable.
The error Error in fitTMB(TMBStruc): negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values (function glmm()) occurs when I run the follwoing global model:
# complexe modell with more variables
glmm_complex <- glmmTMB(meat ~ gender + age_group + member + gender:age_group + gender:member + 
                 (1 | ccrs), 
                 family = binomial, 
                 data = nova)

Anova(glmm_complex)
summary(glmm_complex)

I have already tried following steps to solve my problem:

re-install package Matrix as well as RStudio with the latest version
group the variable ccrs in a variety of ways
set the starting parameter values manually
remove interactions and predictors to make the model more simple

What has worked but doesnt really solve my problem:
When the randomized variable ccrs is removed or simply included as a non-ranodmized variable the model runs without error. I can live with removing the interactions from the model but it is important to consider the randomized variable ccrs in the model.
Are there any other solutions to include a randomized variable with glmm() function and without running on errors?
